# The "Question Feed" is broken

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I'm not sure if this is just happening to me, but this link:

https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/feeds

Results in this:
[image]

*Yes, that is exactly how it is displayed.*

Answer (score 5):

This is [status-by-design](/questions/tagged/status-by-design). The '/feeds' link is the RSS feed for the website, so that is what it should look like.